# How to bypass the special/French characters from JSON to XML using an xslt in datapower

Tags: json, xml, xslt, ibm-datapower, jsonx

I'm trying to send a sepcial/French character like : **ÆÇÈ-1 Çâfé's  Çôrp-Ltd** in the JSON request, but it is failing with the below error:

```
{ "error":{ "code":"4000", "message":"Invalid Request From Consumer. Error Description :0x00c30025 Unable to parse JSON and generate JSONx: illegal character 's' at offset 8951
```

whereas, when I try to pass the same name- **ÆÇÈ-1 Çâfé's  Çôrp-Ltd** as a XML request, it is getting processed with success response.

Please help me resolve the issue with the JSON request

Comment: As per https://jsonlint.com/ this is a valid JSON string. Could you please provide a sample of where this appears in a JSON request so that we can see the context of the error?

Comment: Thanks Tom, Yes it says it is a valid JSON.... but when we send that request as below for the XSLT, it throws the error as mentioned above- Unable to parse JSON and generate JSONx: illegal character                                                                                                PFB the sample JSON request:                                                                "new_account_employer_details": {
"name": "ÆÇÈ-1 Çâfé's  Çôrp-Ltd",
     "street1": "APT666",
     "street2": "189-34 Great George Street","state": "PE",
"mail_code": "C0A1C0",
"country": "124"
    },

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is that your service (a MPGW I assume) is set to `Request data: JSON` and not `XML`.
If `JSON` as request data isn't working either try with `non-XML`.
DataPower runs different parsers/validators depending on the content data type but as long as the JSON itself is valid `JSON` should work, else open a PMR!

If you still can't figure it out test that the incoming data is detected as UTF-8 and not as Latin1. Add a GWS action and feed the INPUT to it and try something like:

```
// This is where we start, grab the INPUT as a buffer
session.input.readAsBuffers(function(readAsBuffersError, data) {

    if (readAsBuffersError) {
        console.error('Error on readAsBuffers:', readAsBuffersError);
    } else {
        let content = data.toString();
        if (content.length === 0) {
            console.error('Empty message found for Request message!');
        } else {
      try {
        // This seems like an overkill solution but we need to know if data fetched is UTF-8 or Latin1
        // If Latin1 we need to wobble it around to not wreck "double-bytes", e.g. Å, Ä or Ö
        const util = require('util');
        const td = new util.TextDecoder('utf8', { fatal: true });
        td.decode(Buffer.from(content));
        console.log('Buffer data is UTF-8!');
      } catch (err) {
        // It is not UTF-8, since it failed so we'll assume it is Latin1. If not it will throw it's own Buffer error or transformation will fail...
        if (err.message === 'The encoded data was not valid for encoding utf-8') {
          const l1Buffer = Buffer.from(content, 'latin1');
          const l1String = l1Buffer.toString('latin1');
          content = Buffer.from(l1String, 'utf8');
          console.log('Buffer data was Latin1, now converted into UTF-8 successfully!');
        }
      }
      session.output.write(content);
        }
    }
});
```